# How to create nested object from nested arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have code like this, that initialize config

```php
    $this->config = array(
        'users' => array(
            array('name' => 'admin',
                  'password' => $password
            )
        ),
        'tokens' => array(),
        'sessions' => array(),
    );
```

that I'm saving to a file using `json_encode($this->config)` and later I load it using

```php
json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'));
```

it create nested objects, I would like to have this nested object when I initialize and the config, **is there a way to create this nested object other then this?**

```php
$this->config = json_decode(json_encode($this->config));
```

Comment: You want your array to become an object, or better a collection of nested objects?

Comment: @moonwave99 Yes, json_encode for assoc array `array('foo' => 'bar')` return  `{"foo": "bar"}` which become an object when you use `json_decode('{"foo": "bar"}')` so instead of `$array['foo']` you access it via `$array->foo` - json_decode create instance of `stdClass`

Comment: Anyway, why don't you just store your data object-wise _the first_ time, without passing for associative arrays?

Comment: Becasue php don't have syntax for creating objects like JSON in javascript and I would need to use something like like `$this->config =  new stdClass(); $admin = new stdClass(); $admin->user = 'admin'; $admin->password = $password; $this->config->users = array($admin); ...` I prefer one extression. I post solution to this.

Comment: But php has _classes_! Just define a `User` class and provide a constructor: you will come with something like `new User('admin', $password)`.

Comment: @moonwave99 Yes I just did that (I miss javascript object creation), but for config I use stdClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to use this function instead

```
function object($array) {
    $object = new stdClass();
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        $object->$k = $v;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

and explicitly call it for assoc arrays

```
$this->config = object(array(
    'users' => array(
        object(array(
            'name' => 'admin',
            'password' => $password
        ))
    ),
    'tokens' => array(),
    'sessions' => array(),
));
```

**EDIT** recursive code

```php
function is_assoc($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        return !is_numeric($keys[0]);
    }
}

function object($array) {
    if (is_assoc($array)) {
        $object = new stdClass();
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            $object->$k = object($v);
        }
        return $object;
    } else {
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to do this - just cast your array to object: `(object)($this -> config)` to obtain what your custom function does.

Comment: @moonwave99 I didn't know that you can cast to functions. But cast is not recursive second function will create object only from first array. But anyway I decide to drop this array to objec thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use this function

```
<?php
function arrayToObject($array) {
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return $array;
    }

    $object = new stdClass();
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
      foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
         $name = strtolower(trim($name));
         if (!empty($name)) {
            $object->$name = arrayToObject($value);
         }
      }
      return $object;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's ok, but it gets rid of numeric indexed arrays [e.g. the `users` array in example given], which should stay as being collections of objects  - just check that `$name` is not numeric.

Comment: @moonwave99 yes it should check if `is_integer(array_keys($array)[0])` and then use `return array_map('arrayToObject', $array);`